# godot character movement on ios

Tags: ios, godot

am using godot to build a game .

this my character movement code

```
func Movement():
if Input.is_action_pressed("Right") and not Input.is_action_pressed("Left"):
    velocity.x = min(velocity.x + ACCELERATION , MAX_SPEED)
    flip = "Right"
    if get_node("Hand").position.x < 0: 
        flip()
    get_node("Camera2D").offset_h = 1 
elif Input.is_action_pressed("Left") and not Input.is_action_pressed("Right"):
    velocity.x = max(velocity.x - ACCELERATION , -MAX_SPEED)
    flip = "Left"
    if get_node("Hand").position.x > 0: 
        flip()
    get_node("Camera2D").offset_h = -1 
else:
    velocity.x = 0
```

its work fine on android but on ios i have to long press the touchScreenButton that i used so the
character mocve
is there is a way to make work on touch like on android

i decrease the delay to 0.005 in (input_devices/pointing/ios/touch_delay) but nothing change . i still have to push the button not touch it , i used touch screen button but in ios i have to push it so the character move unlike android where i have to touch the button so the character move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 150 ms delay for touches on iOS by default (but not on Android). This is imposed by the OS for various reasons, but you can [decrease this value in the project settings](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/42457) (`input_devices/pointing/ios/touch_delay`) and export the project to iOS again.

More explanation can be found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/41452).